# Cannot read property success of undefined in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, promise, angular-promise

In a controller A , I have a method that on click of a submit button stores the data at a MVC controller action method.

```
$scope.groupmembership.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.groupMembershipUserInputForm.$valid) {
        $scope.groupmembershipUploadParams = {
            "chapterCode": $scope.groupmembership.chapterCode,
            "createdDate": $filter('date')(new Date($scope.groupmembership.createdDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
            "endDate": $filter('date')(new Date($scope.groupmembership.endDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
        };

        UploadDataServices.getGroupMembershipUploadParams(
            $scope.groupmembershipUploadParams)
            .success(function (result) {
                $rootScope.$emit(
                    'validateUploadedFilesEvent', 
                    $scope.groupmembershipUploadParams
                );
            });
    }
}
```

**UploadDataServices.getGroupMembershipUploadParams**

```
getGroupMembershipUploadParams: function(uploadParams){
    $http.post(BasePath + "uploadNative/setGroupMembershipUploadParams", uploadParams, {
        headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    }).success(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
},
```

**uploadNativeMVC controller**

```
public async Task<JsonResult> setGroupMembershipUploadParams(GroupMembershipUploadParams arg)
{
    TempData["GroupMembershipUserUplaodDetails"] = arg; //Save the data for later use
    var result = new JsonResult();
    result.Data = "Success"; // Return a Excel Upload Limit Exceeded
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    return result;
}
```

This saved data I want to re-use by other methods in the MVC controller in subsequent calls.

I do not want any response back but just make sure methodB() in angular executes after the data in MVC is saved , I did fired an event after I get success response

```
UploadDataServices.getGroupMembershipUploadParams(
    $scope.groupmembershipUploadParams)
    .success(function (result) {
         $rootScope.$emit('methodB', $scope.groupmembershipUploadParams);
    });
```

I know this result.data in MVC creation is **redundant** ,

```
var result = new JsonResult();
result.Data = "Success"; // Return a Excel Upload Limit Exceeded
result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
return result;
```

**but how to make sure**

```
$rootScope.$emit('methodB', $scope.groupmembershipUploadParams);
```

**fires only after tempData is stored.**

```
UploadDataServices.getGroupMembershipUploadParams(
    $scope.groupmembershipUploadParams)
    .success(function (result)
```

is throwing me error . What can be done more neatly ? I know there are lot of redundant code lines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a `return` in your method, it's going to return `undefined`. That's why you're getting an error.

Fixed:

```
getGroupMembershipUploadParams: function(uploadParams){
    return $http.post(
        BasePath + "uploadNative/setGroupMembershipUploadParams",
        uploadParams, 
        {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
           }
        })
        .success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but all of the returns from MVC just for the sake of returning and checking that events get fired only after successful save in MVC Tempdata are necessary ? Can we avoid that ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. For this part: _but all of the returns from MVC_, are you concerned that returning the string `"Success"` is wasteful? That's not really something to worry about, but you could probably return a `null` response if you want to.

Comment: Yes , I am hard coding it . I just want to make sure that only after a successful save in MVC, I can do $rootScope.$emit , not before that . So is this approach okay ?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder Yes, if you use a `.success()` callback, the callback will only run once the request has completed.